# Enforce type of generic dependent on constructor parameter

Tags: typescript, class, constructor

Is it possible to enforce `T = Tile` when `Iterable<Coords>` is passed to the constructor?

```
class Grid<T extends Tile> {
  tiles = new Map<T>();
  setTile(tile: T) {
    this.tiles.set(tile.toString(), tile);
  }
  constructor();
  constructor(coords: Iterable<Coords>);  // enforce T = Tile in this case
  constructor(tiles: Iterable<T>);
  constructor(input?: Iterable<T> | Iterable<Coords>) {
    if (!input) return;
    for (const t of input) {
      if (t instanceof Tile) {
        this.setTile(t);
      } else {
        this.setTile(new Tile(coord));  // ts(2345) error here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `Tile`, instead of `T` - what value is the generic type giving you?

Comment: I was hoping the user could extend the tile class to include terrain or some other business logic specific to their application.

Comment: That's exactly the problem it's telling you about - a user could try to make a `Grid<TerrainTile>`, but if they pass in an iterable of coordinates the constructor would fill it with vanilla `Tile`s.

Comment: Exactly, this is the problem I'm trying to get around. I want the user to be able to pass `Coord`s, `Tile`s or `TerrainTile`s and have the Map store them appropriately.

Comment: Think about this: if I do something like `new Grid<TerrainTile>([{ x: 0, y: 0 }])`, how does it create `TerrainTile`s _at runtime_? The generic type, as with the other type metadata, is erased. The constructor will only ever create `Tile`s. A cleaner approach might be to have a separate method e.g. `static fromCoords(coords: Iterable<Coords>): Grid<Tile>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may allow passing Tile constructor as fillowing:
https://tsplay.dev/N73JDN

```
class Tile {
  constructor(coord: Coords) { }
}
type Coords = { x: number }

class Tile2 extends Tile { y = 1 }

class Grid<T extends Tile = Tile> {
  tileConstructor: new (c: Coords) => T
  tiles = new Map<string, T>();
  setTile(tile: T) {
    this.tiles.set(tile.toString(), tile);
  }
  constructor();
  constructor(coords: Iterable<Coords>, TileConstructor: new (c: Coords) => T);
  constructor(coords: Iterable<Coords> & (Tile extends T ? unknown : never));
  constructor(tiles: Iterable<T>);
  constructor(
    input?: Iterable<T> | Iterable<Coords>,
    TileConstructor: new (c: Coords) => T = Tile as new (c: Coords) => T
  ) {
    this.tileConstructor = TileConstructor;
    if (!input) return;
    for (const t of input) {
      if (t instanceof Tile) {
        this.setTile(t);
      } else {
        this.addNewTile(t);
      }
    }
  }
  addNewTile(coord: Coords): T {
    let tile = new this.tileConstructor(coord)
    this.setTile(tile);
    return tile;
  }
}
new Grid([{ x: 1 }]) // ok
new Grid<Tile2>([{ x: 1 }]) // error
new Grid([{x: 1}, Tile2]) // ok
```

Comment: Actually it may make sence to keep TileConstructor in the class itself to allow `.addTileByCoord(coord)`-like methods

Comment: Appreciate the answer, would be nice to have an `.addTileByCoord(coord)` method on the class also. Could you add this to your answer to show how this would work?

Comment: @ChrisOram does this answers yours question?